# dompdf showing quesetion marks Instead of arabic characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

While in English dompdf is supporting well, now coming to Arabic it is showing question marks instead of Arabic characters.

My code:

```
//get weekly report of users

public function pdf_content3()
{
    require_once("application/libraries/Dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');

        $tym = date('g:i s');
        $filename = 'order_list'.$tym;

$st_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
$ed_date = $this->input->post('end_date');

$date  = date_create($st_date);
$date2 = date_create($ed_date);
$date3 = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
$date4 = date_format($date2,"Y-m-d");

if( $this->verify_min_level(9) ){

$this->data['orders_list'] = $this->business_orders_m->get_pdf_data($date3,$date4); 

$html="<html><body>";

if(sizeof($this->data['orders_list']) > 0){

$html.="<h1 style='text-align:center'>BUSINESS USER ORDER DETAILS</h1><br><br><table style = 'border: 1px solid black;text-align:center;margin:0px auto;border-spacing: 0.5rem;border-collapse: collapse;'><thead>
<tr><th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>Id No</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>User Name</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>Order Id</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>Date</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>From</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>To</th>
<th style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";

$i = 1;

foreach($this->data['orders_list'] as $date_search){

$status = '';
if($date_search->order_status == 0){
$status = 'Pending';    
}else{
$status = 'Completed';  
}

            $html.="<tr><td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$i."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$date_search->username."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$date_search->order_id."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$date_search->date."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$date_search->pickup_address."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$date_search->drop_address."</td>
            <td style = 'border: 1px solid black;padding:10px'>".$status."</td></tr>";

            $i++;

}

$html.="</tbody>";
$html.="</table>";
}else{
    $html.= '<p><h1 style="text-align:center;color:red;">NO DATA AVAILABLE</h1></p>';
}

$html.="</body></html>";
$this->pdf_create($html,$filename);

        }else{
            redirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
        }
}

public function pdf_create($html,$filename,$stream = TRUE)
{
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your font file does not support Arabic letters?

Comment: then how to over come it any idea ?

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#setting-options

Comment: @saivamshi add your code

Comment: public function pdf_create($html,$filename,$stream = TRUE)
 {
 $html1 = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html1);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf",array('Attachment'=>0));
    }

Comment: @saivamshi can you post your whole html file ?

Comment: @ jagad89 yes you can see my code know

Answer (score 1):

The project Github page has a specific note ([About Fonts & Character Encoding](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#about-fonts--character-encoding)) right in the home page (emphasis mine):

> PDF documents internally support the following fonts: Helvetica,
>   Times-Roman, Courier, Zapf-Dingbats, & Symbol. These fonts only
>   support Windows ANSI encoding. In order for a PDF **to display
>   characters that are not available in Windows ANSI you must supply an
>   external font**.

The code you've shared does not make any attempt to load an external font or use the default *DejaVu* family bundled in the library.