# Problem on Dompdf, Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

Problem on Laravel Dompdf: 
Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored

My Controller :

```
 public function CasePDF($id)
    {
                // echo $id;
      $case_view = Case_a::findOrFail($id);
      $details = Case_details::where('case_id' , $id)->value('case_details');
                // echo "string";
                // return view('pdf.casepdf', compact('case_view','details'));
      if ($case_view->added_by != Auth::user()->id) {
        abort(404);
      }
      $caseNumber = $case_view->case_number;
      $caseNumber .= ".pdf";

      $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.casepdf', compact('case_view','details'));

      return $pdf->download($caseNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the problem is in the Laravel Dompdf for php 7.4

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/636

The best practice approach would be to either wait for a php 7.4 compatible release
Or you can try fix by yourself

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2003#issuecomment-561631196

> Quick fix. Line 2543, add :

```
if (ctype_xdigit($c) && ctype_xdigit($n)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this same issue recently. dompdf 0.8.5, PHP 7.4, setasign/setapdf-merger 2.28

As of PHP 7.4, passing invalid characters (as in "#") causes hexdec to throw a deprecation notice, and that's what appears to be causing the issue.
[PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

So, I found the offending file from the error message stack trace:
/vendor/setasign/setapdf-merger/library/SetaPDF/Core/Type/Name.php:58

I changed that line to:

```
return chr(hexdec(ltrim($matches[0], '#')));
```

Quick fix that worked for me. Now it's time to update the app!

Answer (score 1):

dompdf/dompdf released version 0.8.4 that includes some changes so it will work on PHP 7.4. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.8.4

Anyone reading this, check the version of dompdf/dompdf installed in your project and specify v 0.8.4+ if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your dompdf version >= 0.8.5, this is not related to php 7.4. Including the external fonts used in your project may fix this issue:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontname';
    ...
}

html {
    font-family: 'fontname';
}
```

Inspired from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41143686/4188616).